# Multiple WinWord in Task Manager

Tags: c#

my c# application creates winword in task manager and close properly from taskmanager. but in case my application crashed then the winword remains opened in task manager and cannot able to process those word document.

so in that case i want to kill those winword alone which is created by my application and not all.

please help to finish this.

Comment: Have you already tried something? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i have tried to supress all dialog box while opening the files but no use. i have only idea to kill the particular winword but only that whis is created by my application

Answer (score 1):

When instances of winword.exe are created through interop, they'll have the string "/Automation -Embedding" included in the process command line.

So, if you want to manually kill only your interop winword processes, without killing any user-initiated instances of Microsoft Word, you can open up Mark Russinovich's free ProcessExplorer utility, right click on a line with winword.exe, choose "properties", and look at the command line (in the Image tab). If you see the /Automation switch, you'll know it's an interop process and you can kill it.  Here's how the interop winword.exe will look in ProcessExplorer:

[image: interop winword in Process Explorer]

Comment: i checked but i didnt have that option which is marked as red

Comment: OK, then it sounds like you are not using interoperability. So, how are you starting up WinWord from your application? Please post the code that you use to start it up.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
try
{
    // open your word document
    // process your word document
}
catch
{
    // handle any errors (e.g. provide error messages
}
finally
{
    // close the word document properly
}
```

To prevent orphaned word processes you will need to store the open processes in a central way in your application and close all remaining processes before shutting down the application. Furthermore you could register to the unhandled error event and then close all processes if that happens.

Shutting down word processes if you cannot open a document is no option in most cases, because that document might be opened for editing in a "real" word instance.

Comment: s u r rite. i dont have any problem infact i am using this code. but if my application suddenly closed between file open and close then next time the same file remains open and shows file in use.

Comment: k. thanks nice idea. but please can u tell me how to implement the "central way in your application" concept.

Comment: What kind of application is this? Console? WPF? Silverlight?

Comment: Please answer my last question if further assistance is required